# Regarding loss function

Tags: loss-functions

Does loss function need to be (at least locally) differentiable in order to be used in a model that support definition of loss function (e.g., xgboost, lstm, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

Loss function needs to be differentiable only if you are using optimization algorithm that needs the derivatives. Not every optimization algorithm does, but many do.